# How to handle Laravel Eloquent "WHERE" Query with slash on the value? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My table is like this :

[image]

On the mysql, I try like this :

```
SELECT * FROM players WHERE player_type = 'App\Models\Player'
```

Data does not showing

So, I add slash like this :

```
SELECT * FROM players WHERE player_type = 'App\\Models\\Player'
```

Data showing

Then, In laravel eloquent, I try like this :

```
$select = array(
    'player_type'
);
$query = self::where('player_type', '=', 'App\\\Models\\\Player')
             ->paginate(10, $select, 'page', null, null);
```

Data does not showing

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can I be safe to assume you are using `morph` relationship method?

Comment: @Omisakin Oluwatobi, Yes, I use it

Comment: then you don't have to worry using the with asking by where player type again, once for example if the relationship is players and users then you can simply fetch by somethiing like `User::with('players')->get()`

Answer (score 0):

Just a different approach here, not the solution.

All your models have the same namespace `App\Models\...`. If so, then just save the actual model in your database without its namespace.

```
id        player_type
 1        Player
 2        Player
```

Then later in your controller, you get the palyer type and add the namespace manually when trying to instantiate the Model.

Comment: If it's not a solution, shouldn't this just be a comment?